# How to print all objects in an ArrayList with a specific trait?

Tags: object, methods

I have an `ArrayList` which stores issues. Now I was wondering how I could `print` out all of the objects from this List that have a specific `boolean` variable set to `true/false`.

*For example:* If I have six objects in the list, and two of them have this variable set to false, then only these two objects will be printed.

Comment: Loop through the list, if the bool is set print it

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using Java, and you'd like to loop through the ArrayList printing out any elements where `boolean` is set to either true or false, this should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); i++) {    
          if (boolean) {
            int retval=ArrayList.get(i);    # modify this to reflect the type of object in ArrayList
            System.out.println(retval);
          }       
}
```